# How to make Junit platform test fail if test discovery fails for some classes?

Tags: gradle, junit5, spek

I have a Gradle build using JUnit 5 to run Spek tests.

Some of the tests fail during setup:

```
Feb 17, 2020 4:38:42 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'spek' failed to discover tests
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at <redacted>.SparkEval.generateEvalTaskDescs(SparkEval.kt:157)
        at <redacted>.TestFilterConfigs$1.invoke(TestFilterConfigs.kt:70)
        at <redacted>.TestFilterConfigs$1.invoke(TestFilterConfigs.kt:34)
```

However it doesn't count as error, and test framework just ignores these.

Relevant part of the Gradle config is:

```
  junitPlatform {
    platformVersion "1.0.3"
    filters {
      engines {
        include 'spek'
        include 'junit-vintage'
      }
    }
    enableStandardTestTask true
  }

  test {
    testLogging {
      showStandardStreams = false
    }
    reports {
      junitXml.enabled = true
      html.enabled = true
    }
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
    finalizedBy testReport
  }
```

Is there a configuration option I can use so it fails the tests if there's an error setting up a test suite?

Comment: Have you checked the behaviour using the latest platform version 1.6.0?

Comment: Yes, sadly spek is incompatible with that version. Upgrading to spek 2 and platform version 1.6.0 solves this issue, however that requires rewriting all my tests